# How to get array of row values from JDBC result set

Tags: arrays, jdbc

I have a sql statement that brings back the following rows:

[image]

I would like to obtain these values from a JDBC result set as two objects.  One for the customer with customerNo 1 and the other for customer 2.  I would like the two objects to have another array value with the related Titles with the object values.

The structure would ultimately look like this (in JSON):

{customerNo : 1, ["Object 1", "Object 2", "Object 3"]}, {customerNo : 2, ["Object 4", "Object 5"]}

How can I accomplish this with JDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Map to initially collect the results in the format you want.

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> customerTitles = new HashMap<Integer, Set<String>>();
while(resultSet.next()) {
    Integer custId = resultSet.getInt(1);
    Set<String> titles = customerTitles.containsKey(custId) ? 
            customerTitles.get(custId) : new HashSet<String>();
    titles.add(resultSet.getString(2));
    customerTitles.put(custId, titles);
}
```

Once you have it collected this way, you can iterate over the Map and in turn the Sets within and convert them to JSON

```
// Convert to Json array here using your JSON library
for(Integer custId :  customerTitles.keySet()) {
    for(String title : customerTitles.get(custId)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'd do too. `Set`s can't contain duplicates, which might be an issue. Use a List if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that I can think of.

1. Get the `CustomerNo` first with a `SELECT DISTINCT` query and keep it in a `COLLECTION`.
   Then for every (using a loop) `CustomerNo` in the `COLLECTION` perform a `SELECT Title from table WHERE CustomerNo = <collectionValue>` and create a new `JSON Object` for each `CustomerNo`.
2. Fetch the `RESULTSET` with a `SELECT CustomerNo, Title FROM tablename ORDER BY CustomerNo`.
   In the fetching code (inside the loop) of the `RESULTSET` assign a variable to the `CustomerNo` you are getting from the `RESULTSET` and check for the next row. If you encounter a new `CustomerNo` then create a new `JSON Object`.