# convert resultset to nested json in java

Tags: java, json, resultset

I am trying to convert a resultset into a JSON string in Java.  The data is in the form

```
+---+----------+-------------+---------------+
| id| job_type | question    | response_type | 
+---+----------+-------------+---------------+
| 1 | quote    | question1   | text1         |   
| 2 | quote    | question2   | number2       |   
+---+----------+-------------+---------------+
| 3 | standard | question1   | text2         |   
| 4 | standard | question2   | number2       |   
+---+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

and I want to get JSON in the form

```
{
   "JobType": “Quote",
   "Questions": [{
      "question": “question1",
      "response_type": “ text1",
   }, {
      "question": “question2",
      "response_type": “ number2",
   }],
   “JobType”:”Standard”,
   "Questions": [{
       "question": “question1",
       "response_type": “ number2",
   }, {
       "question": “question2",
       "response_type": “ number2",
   }]
}
```

This is where I have got so far

```
JSONObject jobType = new JSONObject();
List<JSONObject> jobTypeQuestionListIndividual = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

int i = 0;
if (!jobTemplate.next()) {    
        System.out.println("No records found");
} else {
    do {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            jobType.put("JobType",jobTemplate.getString("JobType") );

            JSONObject firstQuestion = new JSONObject();
            firstQuestion.put("question",  jobTemplate.getString("question"));
            firstQuestion.put("response_type",  jobTemplate.getString("response_type"));

            jobTypeQuestionListIndividual.add(firstQuestion);

            jobType.put("Questions",jobTypeQuestionListIndividual);

        } else {
            JSONObject question = new JSONObject();

            question.put("question",  jobTemplate.getString("question"));
            question.put("response_type",  jobTemplate.getString("response_type"));

            jobTypeQuestionListIndividual.add(question);
        }

        i = i+1;

    } while (jobTemplate.next());
}

System.out.println( jobType);
```

but this results in

```
{
   "JobType": “Quote",
   "Questions": [{
      "question": “question1",
      "response_type": “ text1",
   }, {
      "question": “question2",
      "response_type": “ number2",
   },{
      "question": “question1",
      "response_type": “ number2",
   }, {
       "question": “question2",
       "response_type": “ number2",
   }]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've never used JSON with Java, but I suggest you should create a QuestioResponse class with only two String (maybe an integer if you want to keep the ID), and a class JobType that contains a List of QuestionResponse (use a list that conserve order if it's important) and String with jobtype's name. Then once you've transformed all your results sets in those Beans, you can work on them to make a Json object (or even use some API/librares that'll do that for you). It should be easier like that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out how to build the nested json by first creating hashmaps and hashsets. This was inspired by the following answers: 
[How to get an array of two values from jdbc result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728494/how-to-get-array-of-row-values-from-jdbc-result-set) and [Storing a hash map inside another hash map and improving performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864111/storing-a-hashmap-inside-another-hashmap-and-improving-performance)

My code doesn't provide the JSON in exactly the format I originally needed, but it works for me.  I get

{"Quote": [{"question": “question1","response_type": “ text1",},{      "question": “question2", "response_type": “ number2",}],"Standard":[{       "question": “question1","}]}

My updated code is

```
String out = "";
try {
    String jobType = "";
    ResultSet jobTemplate = jobs.getAllJobDetailsTemplate(Integer.parseInt(customerId));
    Map<String, Set<HashMap<String,String>>> jobTypes = new HashMap<String, Set<HashMap<String,String>>>();

    while (jobTemplate.next()) {
        jobType = jobTemplate.getString("JobType");
        Set<HashMap<String,String>> questions = jobTypes.containsKey(jobType) ? jobTypes.get(jobType) : new HashSet<HashMap<String,String>>();
           HashMap<String,String> individualQuestion = new HashMap<String,String>();
             individualQuestion.put("question",  jobTemplate.getString("question"));
             individualQuestion.put("response_type", jobTemplate.getString("response_type"));
           questions.add(individualQuestion);
        jobTypes.put(jobType, questions); 
    }

    out = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jobTypes);
}
```